# Windows Azure Cloud service Auto Scale works if any specific .dll installed on first instance?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I have created one Cloud service which I need to auto scale based on traffic.

In this I registered one specific .dll on server and also did some specific changes in IIS via enable Remote for Cloud service.

Now I am not sure when I set my Cloud service as `Auto Scale Mode` and if new instance create will my register .dll and IIS changes will available for new instance?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a web/worker role instance you're talking about: If you automated the DLL registration (via startup script), then the same registration would take place on all instance as they're spun up.

If you manually registered the DLL (either through RDP or remote PowerShell), then you're going to have trouble:

- the DLL will never be registered on additional instances
- whenever there's maintenance on your original role instance (such as a host OS update) that causes you to have a freshly-paved OS image (including hardware failures), your role instance will no longer have the registered DLL

*All* installation tasks on a web/worker role must be automated, specifically for these reasons. You cannot manually update anything on the role instances, aside from dev/test purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using cloud service and installing dll manually and also doing some changes in IIS. as I am deploying my Classic ASP application which needs to register dll manually.   Also if I take web role then it won't allow me to register dll by script as it thorws some permission error.

Comment: You should ask a separate question about properly automating web role DLL registration then. Just know that what you're currently doing won't work at all in a production environment.